# Replace particular string patter in a string python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have some sentences with emoji Unicode, which consist of Unicode patterns like **U0001**. I need to extract all the string having **U0001** into an array. This is the code that i have tried

```
    import re
    
    pattern = re.compile(r"^U0001")
    sentence = 'U0001f308 U0001f64b The dark clouds disperse the hail subsides and one neon lit rainbow with a faint second arches across the length of the A u2026'
    print(pattern.match(sentence).group()) #this prints U0001 every time but what i want is ['U0001f308']

    matches = re.findall(r"^\w+", sentence)
    print(matches) # This only prints the first match which is 'U0001f308'
```

Any way to extract string to an array?. I don't have much experience in regex.

Comment: Can you try this - (\bU0001\w*)\b

Comment: `^` will only search at the start of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'U0001f30'` is *not* an emoji codepoint! It's a 9-character string beginning with the letter 'U'.

The way to enter unicode codpoints with more than 4 hex characters is `\U0001f308`. Likewise to enter a 4-hexadecimal character codepoint: `\u0001`.

But you can't look for codepoints that start with '0001' as if they were regular character strings. It seems to me you are either looking for the 4-hexadecimal character codepoint `\u0001` or anything in the range `\U00010000 - \U0001FFFF`:

```
import re

sentence = '\U0001f308 \U0001f64b The dark clouds disperse the hail subsides and one neon lit rainbow with a faint second arches across the length of the A \u2026'

matches = re.findall('[\u0001\U00010000-\U0001FFFF]', sentence)
print(matches)

matches -> ['\U0001f308', '\U0001f64b']
```

If for some reason you really had strings beginning with 'U' and not actual codepoints, then:

```
matches = re.findall('U0001(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4})?', sentence)
```

*I have also assumed that emojis can be anywhere in the string and adjacent to any other characters.*